# RethinkDB - Query with count and join

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have two "tables" such as:

- PEOPLE (ID / NAME)

1  | JOHN

2  | MARY

3  | PETER

- MESSAGES (ID / PERSON_ID / TEXT)

1  | 1 | 'Text'

1  | 1 | 'Text 2'

1  | 2 | 'Text 3'

1  | 3 | 'Text 4'

How can I get the number of messages of each person? Just like:

(PERSON_ID / NAME / MESSAGES)

1         | JOHN  | 2

2         | MARY  | 1

3         | PETER | 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
r.db("so").table("messages")
  .group(r.row('person_id')).count().ungroup()
  .map((result) => {
    return result.merge(r.db("so").table("users").get(result('group')));
  })
```

Result looks like this:

```
[
  {"group":1,"id":1,"name":"Dalan","reduction":2},
  {"group":2,"id":2,"name":"Rodger","reduction":3}
]
```

You can further rename the fields as you like with the `.merge` method but this gets you the join and grouping that you wanted!

Let me know if you have any questions.